# webRTC not working when call initiated by FireFox

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am developing a simple webRTC application, using my own server for signaling.

the javascript code is as follow (I have removed the signaling process and unnecessary logic):

```
const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: [
        "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
        "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
      ],
    },
  ],
  iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
};

const callerCandidatesString = "callerCandidates";
const calleeCandidatesString = "calleeCandidates";

var received_offer = null;
var offer = null;
var answer = null;

var peerConnection = null;
let localStream = null;
let remoteStream = null;
    
var constraints = {
  optional: [],
  mandatory: {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
  }
}    


    
async function startMedia(e) {
    
    const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});
    document.getElementById("video1").srcObject = localStream;
    remoteStream = new MediaStream();
    document.getElementById("video2").srcObject = remoteStream;
    
    if (I am the caller) {
        create_the_offer();
    }
    
    if (I am the callee) {
        get_the_offer();
    }
    
}

    
async function create_the_offer() {

    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    registerPeerConnectionListeners();

    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });
    
    var offer = await peerConnection.createOffer(constraints);
    peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(candidate) {
        if (candidate.candidate == null) {

            //save the offer in the server
            --> offer: JSON.stringify(peerConnection.localDescription)},
        }
    }
    
    check_if_there_is_an_answer();
}

    
    
async function get_the_offer() {

    // --> retrieve the offer from the server, then 
    create_answer(offer_from_server);
    
} 


 
async function create_answer(received_offer) {
    
    console.log("Create PeerConnection with configuration: ", configuration);
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    registerPeerConnectionListeners();
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });


    console.log('received offer:' + received_offer)
    my_offer = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(received_offer));
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(my_offer);
    
    
    // collectIceCandidates(peerConnection, calleeCandidatesString, callerCandidatesString);

    peerConnection.addEventListener("track", event => {
      console.log("Got remote track:", event.streams[0]);
      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
        console.log("Add a track to the remoteStream:", track);
        remoteStream.addTrack(track);
      });
    });

    
    const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer(constraints);
    console.log("Created answer:", answer);
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);


    peerConnection.onicecandidate = function (e) {
      if (e.candidate == null) {
      
        // --> send the answer to the server
    }
}   
    
    
    
function check_if_there_is_an_answer() {
    
    // retrieve answer from server. this function is executed several times until the answer is received.
    // when there is an aswer:
    start_remote_connection(answer);
}    
    
    

    
async function start_remote_connection(passed_answer) {
    
    my_answer = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(passed_answer));
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(my_answer);

    peerConnection.addEventListener("track", event => {
      console.log("Got remote track:", event.streams[0]);
      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
        console.log("Add a track to the remoteStream:", track);
        remoteStream.addTrack(track);
      });
        console.log("stream remoto: " + JSON.stringify(remoteStream.getVideoTracks()));
    });
    
    document.getElementById("video1").srcObject = localStream;
    document.getElementById("video2").srcObject = remoteStream;
}
    



async function hangUp(e) {
            
    const tracks = document.getElementById("video1").srcObject.getTracks();
        tracks.forEach(track => {
        track.stop();
    });

    remoteStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());

    peerConnection.close();

    document.getElementById("video1").srcObject = null;
    document.getElementById("video2").srcObject = null;
}





// collect ICE Candidates function below
async function collectIceCandidates(peerConnection, localName, remoteName) {
        const candidatesCollection = null;

        peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", event => {
            if (event.candidate) {
                const json = event.candidate.toJSON();
                candidatesCollection.add(json);
            }
        });
    }
// collect ICE Candidates function above



    



function registerPeerConnectionListeners() {
  peerConnection.addEventListener("icegatheringstatechange", () => {
    console.log(
        `ICE gathering state changed: ${peerConnection.iceGatheringState}`);
  });

  peerConnection.addEventListener("connectionstatechange", () => {
    console.log(`Connection state change: ${peerConnection.connectionState}`);
  });

  peerConnection.addEventListener("signalingstatechange", () => {
    console.log(`Signaling state change: ${peerConnection.signalingState}`);
  });

  peerConnection.addEventListener("iceconnectionstatechange ", () => {
    console.log(
        `ICE connection state change: ${peerConnection.iceConnectionState}`);
  });
}


window.onload = startMedia();
```

If the caller uses chrome and the callee uses FireFox (on localhost, same PC) the code works fine and both users can share their screen.

[output with chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZXUN.png)

If the caller uses FireFox and the callee uses Chrome (still on localhost) the code still works fine, but the connection is not established and users cannot see the screen of the other person. I get no error in the console.

[output with FireFox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcowz.png)

In particular, with FF I am not getting "connection state change: connecting" and then "connection state change: connected".

My guess is that FF and chrome manage the async/await differently, and somehow with FF some values are not ready when actually needed, but cannot figure out why ...

with safari (MacOS) it does not work!!

I then tried it between the computer (with chrome) and an Android phone (chrome browser). It worked the first time I test it, and then never again :(

Does anyone of you has a clue ?

Comment: Note that Firefox does not implement the connectionstatechange event (nor the connectionState attribute) so just because you don't see this happening it doesn't mean the connection does not work. Firefox about:webrtc may provide more insight

Comment: In Firefox, please go to `about:webrtc`, then click *Show details* and check the table under *ICE Stats*